# String to match user input

Tags: java, string, list, search

Is there a way I can it make so if the user makes a search such as "car" or "speakers" then the auction will still be found? Any help would appreciated.

private static void browseAuction() {

```
    System.out.println("---Browse Auction---");

    String[] auctions = {"Car - Honda Civic VTI 1.8 Petrol", "Sony Bluetooth Speakers", "auctionObject" };

    java.util.List<String> list1 = java.util.Arrays.asList(auctions);


    System.out.println("Search::");
    String searchWord = S.next();

    if (list1.contains(searchWord)) {
        System.out.println("Auction Found : ");
        java.util.Arrays.toString(auctions);
    }else {
        System.out.println("No Match Found :");
    }
```

Comment: Or somehow display a list of all the auctions, This would be much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should search and check all auctions. And you can print your results like this.
Try this one.

```
    Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean found = false;
    String[] auctions = {"Car - Honda Civic VTI 1.8 Petrol", "Sony Bluetooth Speakers", "auctionObject" };
    java.util.List<String> list1 = java.util.Arrays.asList(auctions);

    System.out.println("---Browse Auction---");
    System.out.println("Search::");
    String searchWord = S.next().toLowerCase();

    //Searching all auctions for 'searchWord' key.
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++){
        String currentAuction = list1.get(i).toLowerCase();
        if (currentAuction.contains(searchWord)) {
            System.out.println("Auction Found : " + list1.get(i));
            found = true;
        }
    }

    //There is no match for 'searchWord' key.
    if (!found)
        System.out.println("No Match Found :");
```

If you search for 'a'
Result:

```
---Browse Auction---
Search::
a
Auction Found : Car - Honda Civic VTI 1.8 Petrol
Auction Found : Sony Bluetooth Speakers
Auction Found : auctionObject
```

If you search for 'car'

```
---Browse Auction---
Search::
car
Auction Found : Car - Honda Civic VTI 1.8 Petrol
```

If you search for 'none'

```
Search::
none
No Match Found :
```

Comment: No problem, don't forget mark as true answer for my comment, thank you

Comment: No worries mate just did, Im abit confused as how I can get the auctionobject which is made in my placeAuction method to be part of the search. Again any help would appreciated.

Comment: I didn't understand you totally. You want to search key for 'auctionObject'?

Comment: Yes, In my placeBid method the user can create a auction. I would like this auction to be include the search. Sorry if i'm not overly clear. Still new to programming

Comment: When user create new auction, you should add this auction to 'list1' list.
example with pseudo:
list1 = [car auction, house auction]
>> user create new auction which name is 'board auction' on placeBid function. >> add to 'board auction' to list1. >> new list1 =[car auction, house auction, board auction] >> you can search with list1 again

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help , I'll try to give this a go

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
if (list1.toLowerCase().contains(searchWord.toLowerCase())) {
        System.out.println("Auction Found : ");
        java.util.Arrays.toString(auctions);
    }else {
        System.out.println("No Match Found :");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method that performs case insensitive comparison and call it, e.g.:

```
public boolean containsIgnoreCase(List<String> elements, String searchString){
    for(String element : elements){
        if(element.toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In your code:

```
if (containsIgnoreCase(list1,searchWord)) {
    System.out.println("Auction Found : ");
    java.util.Arrays.toString(auctions);
}else {
    System.out.println("No Match Found :");
}
```

Here's another example that uses Java 8's `stream`:

```
public boolean containsIgnoreCase(List<String> elements, String searchString){
    return elements.stream()
            .filter(e -> e.toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase()))
            .findFirst()
            .isPresent();
}
```